# How to parse json in jquery using url

Tags: java, jquery, html

I am totally new to **jquery** and am not able to parse the following **json**. I am using icenium and have included this function in my js folder.This is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({ 
                type: 'GET', 
                url: 'http://young-wildwood-2240.herokuapp.com/api/v4/options.json', 
                data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
                success: function (data) { 
                                    var names = data
                    $('#body').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: is that the same domain your server is on? if not, you need to use `dataType:jsonp`, if it is your server, then use `dataType:json`. Setting the data type automatically assumes the returned data is a JSON string, and internally parses the JSON for use. you'll need to `console.log(data)` to see how the JSON is structured. It's probably going to be something like `$.each(data, function(i,name){ $('body').append(name) });`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to attribute the tag dataType to json. 
If you have a prefixes in array, use them to get a value.

```
 $.ajax({ 
                type: 'GET', 
                url: 'http://young-wildwood-2240.herokuapp.com/api/v4/options.json', 
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
                success: function (data) { 
                    var names = data;
                    console.log(data.id);
                    console.log(data.question_id);
                    $('#body').html(data);
                }
            });
```

Sorry my bad english, i'm not american.